# Set is reverse sorted by default for a list having negative integer

Tags: python-3.x

```
n = int(input())
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
s = set(arr)
print(s)
print(list(s)[len(s) - 2])
```

**Input**:

```
4
57 57 -57 57
```

**Output**:

```
{57, -57}
57
```

I am trying to find the second largest number in the given list. In the above code the set is reverse sorted which should not be the case. Why is this happening ?

Comment: [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)s have no order you should rely on... use a `list`, sort it and extract the element you want.

Comment: Because `57 % 8` is smaller than `-57 % 8`.

Comment: `"sets have no order you should rely on"` - IKR, but then why does `print(set([4, 57, 57, -57, 57]))` ___always___ print `{57, 4, -57}` ??????? :puzzled:

Comment: @Programmer Because `4 % 8` is in between.

Comment: @Programmer even when an order isn't guaranteed, you may accidentally get one or at least get consistent results.  At least today.

Comment: @MarkRansom `"At least today"` - okay, will retry this tomorrow, then ! LOL

Comment: @Programmer With strings you might already get different orders today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `set` doesn't have a defined order of any kind.  You need to convert the set to a `list` then explicitly sort it.  `sorted` will produce a list automatically.

```
print(sorted(s)[-2] if len(s) >= 2 else None)
```